# How to convert Strava zone data to something familiar

Tags: strava

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the pace from the Strava API (zones).
Would be nice to have it in kph or mins per km.
Thanks in advance

Sample response:

```js
    {
        "score": 8,
        "distribution_buckets": [
            {
                "max": 2.612871112678786,
                "min": 0,
                "time": 450
            },
            {
                "max": 3.0355414397297658,
                "min": 2.612871112678786,
                "time": 582
            },
            {
                "max": 3.38136261640784,
                "min": 3.0355414397297658,
                "time": 579
            },
            {
                "max": 3.6119100675265563,
                "min": 3.38136261640784,
                "time": 542
            },
            {
                "max": 3.842457518645273,
                "min": 3.6119100675265563,
                "time": 550
            },
            {
                "max": -1,
                "min": 3.842457518645273,
                "time": 366
            }
        ],
        "type": "pace",
        "resource_state": 3,
        "sensor_based": true
    }
```

Comment: how do you retrieve this data? I didn't find it on strava docs.

Comment: You can find it under https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getZonesByActivityId

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that ActivityZone also has type "pace" (https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-models-ActivityZone). Is it supported? I can't understand what these numbers represent: can you compare them with other data from your activity?

Comment: maybe they representing speed in m/s? with a speed of 3,84245751864527 m/s you run a km in 260s so 4:20/km.

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much! It's supported but not documented.